# Lightning 1.8 in Thunderbird 16.0.2 doesn't work under Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, thunderbird, lightning

I just had to redo my laptop and choose Ubuntu 12.10 (had 12.04 before). Now I encounter a problem with Lightning, the calendar app for Thunderbird.

My Thunderbird is of version 16.0.2 and I installed Lightning right from the add-ons site inside TB it is of version 1.8 . 
Anyway I cannot do anything in Lightning. I cannot open the Properties of a calender, it actually won't even properly show the calendar grid at all. Not even the default calendar "Private" works.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you.

-Jakob.

Comment: Thunderbird and Lightning are not products of Ubuntu. They have had issues mating different distributions of TB and Lightning in the past. TB is a Mozilla product. Lightning is a third party dev product. AFAIK TB 16.0.0 and Lightning 1.8 work. So, downgrade your TB and live with it. NOT A UBUNTU ISSUE.

Comment: We update lightning when we update Thunderbird in Ubuntu.

Comment: @micahg you have the authoritative answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `xul-ext-lightning` package.  The version from addons.mozilla.org won't work with amd64 systems.

Comment: Thanks alot RolandiXor and micahg. I know its not a Ubuntu-issue but I couldn't find help on the Thunderbird or Lightning pages and I figured people on here would use TB as well! Thanks